# How to find and quantify duplicate vertices on a polygon/polyline in ArcGIS 10.0

Tags: arcgis-10.0, polygon, error, reports, vertices

I need to clean up topological errors in various shapefiles and databases. I did read that the Repair Geometry tool could clean duplicate vertices but how can I know the number of errors before and after using this tool, to ensure these errors were repaired?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.0. I have no programming skils.

Comment: Use the Topology Errors Toolset - you need to create Topology rules first http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Export_Topology_Errors/00170000015w000000/

Answer (score 1):

Run the [Check Geometry](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000034000000) tool first. This creates an output table listing feature level geometry issues.